# How to get an XmlElement inside XmlElement.InnerXml?

Tags: c#, xpath, xquery

I have an `XmlElement` whose `InnerXml` property value (a `string`) is:

```
<star:Code name="SalesCode" xmlns:star="http://www.starstandard.org/STAR/5">ZQ82003</star:Code>
<star:EffectivePeriod xmlns:star="http://www.starstandard.org/STAR/5">
   <star:StartDateTime>2017-12-30T00:00:00Z</star:StartDateTime>
   <star:EndDateTime>9999-12-31T00:00:00Z</star:EndDateTime>
</star:EffectivePeriod>
```

From this, I need to find the `star:StartDateTime` element, and obtain it as a first-class `XmlElement` so that I can get the value (in this case `2017-12-30T00:00:00Z`) via `InnerText`. I can't figure out how to do this. It would be great if I could somehow call `SelectNodes()` against that 
`InnerXml` like this:

```
innerXml.SelectNodes("/star:EffectivePeriod/star:StartDateTime")
```

I could do it that way within the full `XmlDocument`, but I got down to this particular `XmlElement` by looping, logic, and filters. So I cannot look within the entire scope of an `XmlDocument`; I need to search merely within this particular snippet of xml.

How can this be done?

Comment: short of one that you likely tried (wrapping in `"<root>"` + … + "</root>" and loading string into XmlDocument) no...

Comment: Let's say you've selected an `XmlElement el`. So now you can simply use `el.SelectSingleNode()` method.

Comment: As Kirill said, if you have an element node you can use its `SelectSingleNode` or `SelectNodes` methods, just make sure you use a relative XPath expression going downwards to the children e.g. `var nsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(); nsManager.AddNamespace("star", "http://www.starstandard.org/STAR/5"); var dateEl = el.SelectSingleNode("star:EffectivePeriod/star:StartDateTime", nsManager);`

Answer (score 0):

you can get the first instance of this element.

```
//*[local-name()='EffectivePeriod'][1]/*[local-name()='StartDateTime']
```